# Slide out jquery div only works on one button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, slide

please see [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/zxu7w/93/)

html

```
 <div id="getitnow">btn 1</div>
 <div id="getitnow">btn 2</div>
 <div id="getitnow">btn 3</div>
 <div id="getitnow">btn 4</div>

 <div id="slideout">
   <div id="containclickme">
   </div>
 </div>
```

css

```
#slideout {
background: #666;
position: relative;
width: 300px;
height: 80px;
right:-300px;
margin-top:50px;
float:right;
}

#getitnow {
padding:10px;
border:1px solid #ccc;
width:100px;
}
```

script

```
$(function () {
// cache the sliding object in a var
var slideout = $('#slideout');
// click-me not clickme
$("#getitnow").toggle(function () {
    // use cached object instead of searching
    slideout.animate({
        right: '0px'
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 500
    });
}, function () {
    // use cached object instead of searching        
    slideout.animate({
        right: '-300px'
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 500
    });
});
});
```

I am trying to get the slide out div to work no matter which button you click.

How ever it only slides out when you click the first button?

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: All the buttons are having the same id's change them , id  should be unique check fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/zxu7w/95/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use classes:

```
<div class="getitnow"></div>
```

cause we're not allowed to have multiple `ID` in the DOM.

and **this is all you need:**

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zxu7w/94/)**

```
var $slideout = $('#slideout');
$(".getitnow").click(function () {
    var inView = parseInt($slideout.css('right'), 10) < 0;
    $slideout.stop().animate({ right: (inView ? 0 : -300) }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class instead of id,same id's cannot be used in the page.

Comment: thank you that did the trick @Sharath, simple but very effective.